# How to publish the NewRelic tags using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: tag-manager

The tag for NewRelic consists of 2 parts: one for the head and one in the body. How can I publish this tags using Google Tag Manager?

Answer (score 2):

Google Tag Manager [does not support two part tags](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/2787990):

> Certain tags with snippets in the header and the footer. While you can use event based rules on gtm.load to fire some of these tags (see the [developer documentation](http://developers.google.com/tag-manager/)), two-part tags usually imply some need for synchronously loading tags.

It sounds like you are out of luck in regards to this particular tag.